# Line bundles and vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

1. Is there a classification of vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$?  I know that the analogue of Grothendieck's splitting theorem is not true for $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$.
2. Is it true that any line bundle on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is of the form $\mathcal O(m,n) = p_1^*(\mathcal O(m)) \otimes p_2^*(\mathcal O(n))$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ denote the projections on the two factors?

Comment: 2 is true by the exponential exact sequence $ H^1(X,\mathcal O_X) \to H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^\times) \to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$, plus a computation of $H^1(\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_X)$ and $H^2(\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1,\mathbb Z)$, via the Kunneth formula, from the well known-cohomology of $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: For each triple $(r,c_1,c_2)$ there is a moduli space of stable vector bundles, which is not well understood. There is a lot of literature on the subject. 

Comment: For some further references, see <http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21854/vector-bundles-on-mathbbp1-times-mathbbp1>.

Comment: Angelo was trying to link to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21854/vector-bundles-on-mathbbp1-times-mathbbp1

Comment: @Sasha "There is a lot of literature on the subject." Can you give examples? I find nothing specific for $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ except Huh: "Moduli of stable sheaves on a smooth quadric and a Brill–Noether locus" and Huh: "Cubic symmetroids and vector bundles on a quadric surface". I do find much work on complex surfaces that is not specific to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Answer (score 8):

As Will Sawin remarks in the comments, the answer to your question (2) is "yes," either via the exponential exact sequence or by an easy application of the "[theorem of the square](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~bmoonen/boek/LineBund.pdf)," (which works e.g. over a general field).

The answer to your question (1) is rather more interesting--while there is no classification of vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ (that I know of), there *is* a splitting theorem analogous to Grothendieck's result.  First, it's worth noting that there is a result of Horrocks generalizing Grothendieck's theorem to projective spaces of arbitrary dimension:

> **Theorem.**  (Horrocks)  Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Then $E$ is a direct sum of line bundles if and only if $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n, E(r))=0$ for $0<i<n$ and all $r$.

Note that if $n=1$, this is precisely Grothendieck's splitting theorem--a good place to learn about this result and its cousins is [Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces](http://books.google.com/books/about/Vector_Bundles_on_Complex_Projective_Spa.html?id=OG348syTqC8C) by Okonek et al.  It is this theorem which generalizes to $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Indeed, a literally identical theorem to Horrocks' result above works for a quadric surface $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (a vector bundle splits if and only if the middle cohomology of all of its twists $E(n)$ vanishes).  One reference is [this paper](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/9843/1/cohen_macaulay_hypersurface_1987.pdf) by Buchweitz, Greuel, and Schreyer; the relevant comments are Conjecture B and Remark 2 on page 169.  Conjecture B gives a (conjectural) generalization to smooth hypersurfaces; I don't know too much about this subject, so I have no idea what the status of this conjecture is.

Of course, this is far from a classification of vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$--that said, I think that such a classification (at anywhere near the level of completeness of the classification on $\mathbb{P}^1$) is well beyond current technology.  Vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^2$ are already quite interesting and complicated.

Comment: The updated link for the "theorem of the square" is https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/BookAV/LineBund.pdf