# Holomorphic line bundles on arbitrary simplicial toric varieties as restrictions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, toric-varieties

In the question titled "[Line bundles and vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120081/line-bundles-and-vector-bundles-on-mathbb-p1-times-mathbb-p1?rq=1)" it was explained how any holomorphic line bundle on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is of the form $\mathcal O(m,n) = p_1^*(\mathcal O(m)) \otimes p_2^*(\mathcal O(n))$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ denote the projections on the two factors.

In addition, in ["Monad Bundles in Heterotic String Compactifications"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.2875.pdf), it is explained in Section 3.1 that for a complete intersection Calabi-Yau (CICY) (defined as an intersection of zero loci of polynomials in an ambient space, which is a product of $m$ projective spaces $\mathbb{P}^{n_i}$), denoted $X$, its holomorphic line bundles $\mathcal{O}_X(k^1,\ldots,k^m)$ can be obtained by restricting $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n_1}}(k^1)\otimes\ldots\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n_m}}(k^m)$ to $X$.

I would like to know how to generalize the above to holomorphic line bundles on an arbitrary simplicial toric variety. Is it possible to show that a holomorphic line bundle on a simplicial toric variety
$$
X=(\mathbb{C}^N \backslash U)/(\mathbb{C}^*)^m,
$$ 
denoted $\mathcal{O}_X(k^1,\ldots,k^m)$, is equal to the restriction of a holomorphic line bundle of the form 
$$
\mathcal O_{X_1}(k^1) \otimes \mathcal O_{X_2}(k^2)\otimes\dots\otimes \mathcal O_{X_m}(k^m)
$$
to $X$, where $X$ can be defined as an intersection of zero loci of polynomials in the ambient space $X_1\times X_2\ldots \times X_m$? All the $X_i$ here are spaces which have Picard number equal to 1.

Comment: I do not quite understand your question.  Are you asking whether the Picard group of a projective, toric variety with only finite quotient singularities has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of globally generated invertible sheaves?  That is true simply because the Picard group is a finitely generated, free Abelian group and the ample cone is open.

Comment: I am not interested solely in projective toric varieties, I am interested in any simplicial toric variety. Such a variety can be defined as in equation 15.81 of  http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf .

Comment: The footnote on that *very* page of the textbook repeats the well-known characterization of projective, toric varieties with only finite quotient singularities as the Geometric Invariant Theory quotients for the actions of certain connected multiplicative subgroup schemes of the coordinate torus with its standard action on complex affine space.  Thus, your toric manifolds are projective, toric varieties.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for pointing that out. Would I then be correct in saying that for the projective, toric varieties I am interested in, $\mathcal{O}_X(k^1,\ldots,k^m)=\iota^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n_1}}(k^1)\otimes\ldots\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n_m}}(k^m))$, where $\iota$ is the inclusion map $\iota:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times \ldots \times \mathbb{P}^{n_m}$?

Comment: For a projective, toric variety, there exists a closed immersion $\iota:X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times \dots \times \mathbb{P}^{n_m}$ such that every holomorphic invertible sheaf on $X$ is of the form $\iota^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n_1}}(k_1)\boxtimes \dots \boxtimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n_m}}(k_m))$ for a unique ordered $m$-tuple of integers $(k_1,\dots,k_m)$.  In fact, that is true for every projective variety whose Picard group is a finitely generated, free Abelian group.

Comment: @JasonStarr That was very helpful. I noticed you used the external tensor product '$\boxtimes$' here. Does its definition agree with the one in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/external+tensor+product ?

Comment: @JasonStarr I think the toric manifolds described in the textbook are not all projective. If you look at pages 367, 368, and 372, noncompact Calabi-Yaus such as $\mathcal{O}(-N)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{N-1}$, $\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{1}$ and ALE spaces are also included, and I don't see how they can be immersed in compact projective spaces.